# Installing Scanner Driver for Brother MFC295CN

Tags: 12.10, scanner, brother

I am trying to get the scanner working on my Brother MFC295CN all-in-one, but Brother's website is so confusing that I can't figure it out to save my own life. Is there anyone who has done this successfully, and if so, can you explain how you installed it? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

This article answers the question:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1340908

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.